# Function to return only date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a function to convert a textbox value to date. 
I want to store the converted date in a datetime field in my business object with only date and not time like in format(yyyy-MM-dd)

My function is returning date along with time

```
public static DateTime ExtractDate(string myDate)
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (myDate != null)
    {
        try
        {
            result=DateTime.Parse(myDate, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("DateTime conversion error");
        }
    }
    return (result.Date);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTime itself always includes a time, in the case when you're setting it equal to a 'date' then the time will be 00:00:00.  When it comes to displaying the string you'll need to use a format string that includes just the date part.

Comment: What always puzzled me about this is what happens when you change the timezone by +/- an hour. Does the date change then?

Comment: @jdv: Where specifically would you be changing the timezone?

Comment: Thanks for replying Will. I want to store the result in Datetime Field in business object but I only want the date part. I don't want to change the business object type to string. Is there any way ?

Comment: @Popo: There's no type in .NET representing just a date.

Comment: @Popo: Create your own class if you need a date that is just a date - you can't inherit from DateTime, though, so you'll need to encapsulate a DateTime instance (unless you want to implement a lot of the functionality from scratch).

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
result = DateTime.Parse(...).Date;
```

Therre's no need to convert the date/time back to a string first. The resulting `DateTime` will just be midnight on the relevant date.

I see that you're adjusting to universal time - you need to be aware that that may change the date. Dates are inherently local - i.e. my August 25th may well start at a different time to yours due to time zones. Alternatively, you could parse it *as if it were in UTC to start with* and treat it that way. You just need to be careful with what you're doing - you could run into problems where midnight doesn't exist on some days in some time zones. (Been there, done that...)

I would also suggest using `DateTime.TryParseExact` and specifying the input format. In particular, if you only expect users to enter dates, then specify appropriate date formats. Using `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact` means you don't have to catch an exception to notice that the user hasn't entered a valid date.

EDIT: Just to clarify: .NET doesn't have a type representing "just a date". [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) does, but that's not ready for production yet :( Normally you'd just use a `DateTime` and ignore the time part.

Comment: @onof: I hadn't noticed that bit, but I've clarified now. Basically, converting it back into a string isn't helping.

Comment: Whatever I use since I am storing the result inside a DateTime field in Business Object so it is all the same. Thanks for the useful info though, I would use a tryParseExact function at DB class level.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` property returns a DateTime with time set to "00.00:00". You can not remove time from a DateTime, you can avoid to show it in the GUI using `string.Format("d", yourDate)`.

Comment: I want to store only date in DateTime myDate; inside my business object. This I have to pass to DB layer.

Comment: You can't with a DateTime. Which DB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the method and return a string instead of a DateTime, because there is always time attached (therefor also the name DateTIME ;-))

If you return a string, you can do something like:

```
return DateTime-object.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Good luck!